# WatchApp Interface.storyboard objects not shown?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, watchkit

Today opened my project and the interface storyboard file is not displaying correctly. Specifically, the objects on the main interface is not been drawn by storyboard for some reason (see picture). It just shows black. The object is added there as can be seen in the left pane. App runs fine too! But now I can't modifiy this interface because non of the objects appear.

Restarting XCode doesn't do anything either. Help!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, answering my own question again. Just found out that a setting for all the views is being unchecked. I don't remember unchecking them, but after checking them again, the views appear again.

[image]

I guess this has something to do with size class. Since Watch app has 2 size to support - 38 and 42mm, all your views must conform to those.